# How many volumes does The Irregular at Magic High School currently have?

Tags: the-irregular-at-magic-high-school

I finished watching *The Irregular at Magic High School* and I really liked its story, so I would like to read the novels, but first I would like to know how many are available in English, and how many there are in total.

Comment: Have you tried checking the wiki article for that? Wiki is generally a good place to find out how many volumes of a light novel have been released and how many have been translated to English.

Comment: And if it's still ongoing, the answer will change in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so-far 20 volumes released in the English language the US publisher Yen Press for the "High School" series.

In totality, in its original Japanese release, as of this post, there are 32 compiled and released novel volumes for the "High School" series with two appendix novels (which are collection of the short stories of the "High School" series, including the IF short story chapters (in Appendix 2) which happen between Vol. 19 and 20).

There are 9 spin-off volumes (*Plan to Assassinate Tatsuya Shiba* (4 volumes) and *Cygnus Maidens* (5 volumes)) of web novels.

There are also 6 volumes of the sequel series *Magian Company* which is set post-"High School" series.

There is an [additional Japanese-language web novel](https://dengekibunko.jp/title/mahouka/novels/) released to accompany the "Girl Who Summons the Stars" anime movie.